# How can I see the list of IP numbers I have been logging in with in recent times?

Tags: support, login

I somehow tapped somewhere by mistake, and a list appeared with all the IP numbers and dates of my recent logins. Where can I find that again? It seems interesting.

Comment: Hmm...not sure. With my moderator superpower I can get to that kind of thing, but I didn't know that it was available to users (even for themselves--it certainly shouldn't be available for other users).

Comment: I swear I saw that. I even realized that my router had been a long time running, since my IP hadn`t changed for many days. Then I tapped on somewhere else and it went away...

Answer (score 5):

There's nowhere on the site itself that you can find this information. It is logged internally, but not exposed.

However, if you use Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider to log in (which you do), you can view your login history there: https://openid.stackexchange.com/user

If you use a different authentication provider (such as Google or Facebook), you'll have to turn to them to find your login history and associated IPs (I know Google provides this information in some fashion; not sure about anyone else).

Comment: Thanks for the revision Shog ;-)

Comment: Your welcome. For what it's worth, you could have just pinged me on the answer I edited.